# Create multiple entry box using for loop in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Hi i have a integer value and based on the value i have to create the entry boxes in a tcl/tk gui. So i did something like this:

```
    set frame1 [::hwt::LabeledFrame [::hwt::WindowRecess editThicknessWindow].frame1 "Current List: " \
                                                        -expand 0 -relief flat -anchor e -side top -pady 15]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $length_Thickness} {incr i} {
        set Entry_No_$i [::hwt::AddEntry $frame1.Entry_No_[eval $i] label "List Values_$i :" labelwidth 15 \
          entryWidth 10 anchor nw validate real text [namespace current]::arr_attribOptionsValue(Thickness)[$i] state normal \
          withoutPacking -textvariable [namespace current]::lst_Value[$i] ]
          pack $Entry_No_[eval $i] -side top -anchor nw -padx 10 -pady 10
    }
```

So let's say i have the integer number as 3 then i have to create 3 entry boxes. I have a list "arr_attribOptionsValue(Thickness)" with 3 values in it so i want the values from the list to be populated in the entryboxes. Since i am new to tcl/tk so not sure if the syntax is correct or if i am missing something. I am confused like i am creating the tk variable Entry_No_$i and in the pack i am using $Entry_No_[eval $i] so will these two refer to the same value or is it wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you're creating variables like `$Entry_No_[eval $i]` then I *really* think you're going about it the wrong way. Such compound variables are really much more easily done as array elements, such as `Entry_No($i)`, with no `eval` in there to confuse things (or `$Entry_No($i)` to read from the element instead of name it).

Secondly, `[namespace current]::arr_attribOptionsValue(Thickness)[$i]` is even more likely to be wrong, especially as `$i` will be an integer. You can't address an element of a list like that (it't been suggested that it *ought* to be possible, but that's not going to happen in the next few months for sure, and certainly not in combination with an array like that). Instead, the simplest mechanism is to use another array that you populate from the source list and to use a trace to couple back if necessary. (Traces are a more advanced technique; ask another question if you need them.) Populating the working array from list might be done like this:

```
set i 0
foreach item $arr_attribOptions(Thickness) {
    set varname arr_attribOptions(Thickness,$i)
    set $varname $item
    incr i
}
```

Yes, you can store a variable name in a variable. (When reading, use `[set $varname]` to do the double dereference.)

Thirdly, widget names are best if they don't contain most non-alphanumeric characters (except `.`, of course) and don't start any component with a capital letter (for technical reasons relating to window classes).

Fourthly, please use `variable` (or `upvar` or `namespace upvar`) to avoid having to use fully-qualified variables.

---

Overall, we can use these techniques together to get something like this:

```
set frame1 [::hwt::LabeledFrame [::hwt::WindowRecess editThicknessWindow].frame1 "Current List: " \
        -expand 0 -relief flat -anchor e -side top -pady 15]

namespace upvar [namespace current] \
        arr_attribOptions attribs arr_values values lst_Value valueList
set i 0
foreach item $attribs(Thickness) {
    set attribs(Thickness,$i) $item
    set values($i) [lindex $valueList $i]
    incr i
}

for {set i 0} {$i < $length_Thickness} {incr i} {
    set Entry_No($i) [::hwt::AddEntry $frame1.entry_No_$i label "List Values_$i :" labelwidth 15 \
            entryWidth 10 anchor nw validate real text arr_attribOptions(Thickness,$i) state normal \
            withoutPacking -textvariable [namespace current]::arr_values($i)]
    pack $Entry_No($i) -side top -anchor nw -padx 10 -pady 10
}
```

I don't know that I've identified all the problems yet (and most Tcl programmers don't use Hungarian type prefixes on variable names) but it is a lot closer to idiomatic now.

Comment: The `::hwt::AddEntry` command looks to my eyes like it needs much more work, but I've no time to do it myself…

Comment: Thanks for the help Donal, the ::hwt::AddEntry command is nothing but the AddEntry command of tk. Its just the namespace thing i guess we have been using it with.